# Android - Back Button to restart Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 4 Activities and my navigation is like this :

**first activity --> second activity --> third activity --> fourth activity --> third activity**

when I press **back** now from the '**third activity**' , it goes to the fourth activity . However I want it to go to the **second activity**. So, I have overridden **onBackPressed()** method in third activity to : **startActivity(this , SeconActivity.class)**

Problem : When I first navigate from **first activity --> second activity** , I **enable** and **disable** buttons based on some inputs from the first activity in the **onCreate**() method. So, I want to preserve these changes when I navigate from third activity --> second activity . Any ideas ?

Comment: how the fourth activity defined in the manifest?

Comment: To go from Activity4 to Activity3 you can just call `finish()` in Activity4 (assuming that you still have Activity1, Activity2 and Activity3 in the activity stack (ie: you didn't `finish()` them. Then, when you press the BACK key in Activity3 it just returns to Activity2 (doesn't recreate it).

Answer (score 1):

Start the 4th activity via a startActivityForResult. When you want to call the 3rd activity again, just return the results required to configure the 3rd activity as you want it to be, via an [`onActivityResults()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

3rd activity psuedo-code:

```
final int FOURTH_RESULTS=101;

startActivityForResults(Intent fourthActivityIntent, FORTH_RESULTS

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case FORTH_RESULTS:
            //Do stuff here
            break;
    }
}
```

4th activity psuedo-code (Place this where you used to call the 3rd level)

```
Intent result = new Intent();              
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
```

See also [the API](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: The problem is NOT when I navigate from 4th to 3rd . It is when I press BACK from 3rd activity. Here is exactly what I want :
When I press back from 3rd activity I want it to RESTART the 2nd activity and NOT RECREATE it.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the activity launch modes for info on this subject, singleTop has worked for me in the past.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do complicated flows I recommend using this library

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/wizardpager/

It is a good way of enforcing a sort of flow into your android app.